# Unable to import spring boot dependencies to child module from parent module

Tags: spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

I have a root project which has all my spring dependencies and 1 child project(DatabaseService) where I am inheriting all the dependencies from the parent project.

**parent-pom.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>ParentService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>DatabaseService</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.version>1.0.0</project.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-adapter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-function-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-xray-recorder-sdk-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.dummy</groupId>
                <artifactId>databaseservice</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.11.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>aws</shadedClassifierName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

**Child-pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.dummy</groupId>
        <artifactId>ParentService</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>databaseservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>DatabaseService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

But the databaseService is throwing compilation errors. It is unable to resolve any of the spring-boot dependencies.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The declared elements are inherited from the parent POM, but they are inside `<dependencyManagement>`. Elements of `<dependencyManagement>` are *not* dependencies of your project. They only declare standard versions.

These standard versions are used for transitive dependencies and if you don't specify a version yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define **all dependencies for child application** in your child-pom but without version. Maven won't add all parents libraries to children projects.

Comment: I have defined all the dependencies in my child module also (as u can see in the question). But still it does not work

Comment: Are you sure that `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` is the _only_ dependency you need in your child project? Because that is the only one you are declaring.

Comment: Could you provide log?